# How to order a sports league table in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I already have a league standings table, however, I want to make it take into account that 2 draws are equal to a win, and in a tie, lowest points against takes precedence.

Currently shows like below, but technically Team2 should have won:

```
Team    W   L   T   PF  PA  PCT 
—————————————————————————————————
Team1   7   3   0   247 139 0.7000
Team2   6   2   2   220 122 0.6000 
Team3   6   4   0   191 191 0.6000
Team4   4   5   1   167 201 0.4000 
Team5   3   6   1   142 202 0.3000
Team6   2   8   0   193 305 0.2000
```

This is the SQL:

```
SELECT team
 , COUNT(*)  played
 , SUM(win)  wins
 , SUM(loss) lost
 , SUM(win)/count(*) pctWon
 , SUM(draw) draws
 , SUM(SelfScore) ptsfor
 , SUM(OpponentScore) ptsagainst
 , SUM(SelfScore) - SUM(OpponentScore) goal_diff
 , SUM(3*win + draw) score
FROM (
  SELECT team
 , SelfScore
 , OpponentScore
 , SelfScore > OpponentScore win
 , SelfScore < OpponentScore loss
 , SelfScore = OpponentScore draw
  FROM (
    SELECT HomeTeam team, HomeScore SelfScore, AwayScore OpponentScore
    FROM Game
    union all select AwayTeam, AwayScore, HomeScore
    FROM Game
   ) a
) b
GROUP BY team
ORDER BY wins DESC, draws DESC, lost ASC, goal_diff DESC;
```

Comment: `mysql_` is deprecated.

Comment: Upvoted: this is a specific and clear question, featuring a prior attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at your `ORDER BY` clause: you are effectively asking for the results to be ordered by order of wins descending. This rule takes preference over all the others, so obviously Team1 wins.

```
ORDER BY wins DESC, draws DESC, lost ASC, goal_diff DESC;
```

> I want to make it take into account that 2 draws are equal to a win,
>   and in a tie, lowest points against takes precedence.

Then that would be:

```
ORDER BY (wins*2 + draws) DESC, lost ASC, ptsagainst DESC;
```

Comment: The first expression seems to give the desired result (but it really depends on the interpretation of the "two draws is equal to a win" specification... do we want "6 wins and 1 draw" ordered before "6 wins and 0 draws", seems reasonable to me, and is what that expression accomplishes. But from the specification given, it seems like the second expression in the ORDER BY should reference `ptsagainst`, rather than `lost` or `goal_diff`.

Comment: @spencer7593 No, the first expression does not give the desired result. You can see in the original post that this expression will place Team1 over Team2 (because Team1 has more wins) while, according to spec, Team2 should be over Team1 (same points by wins and ties, but less losses). But you are right about `ptsagainst`, I will edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Taking from abl's answer, I changed the pre-existing `, SUM(3*win + draw) score` to 
 `, SUM((win*2 + draw)- loss) score`

Then just put the `ORDER BY score DESC, ptsagainst DESC;`

This gave the desired results!

Thanks guys

Comment: I don't think this expression is correct. For example, a team with 3 wins, 0 draws and 10 losses would score lower than a team with 0 wins, 0 draws and 0 losses, which goes against your specification.

Comment: I have amended to `ORDER BY pctWon DESC, score DESC, ptsagainst DESC;` which should solve this, therefore a played record will place higher than an unplayed record. Thanks for spotting